# Не работает кодировка в бинарном файле C

Tags: c, visual-studio, файлы

Во-первых, если я заношу массив чаров в бинарный файл, текст не кодируется(с интами, дабл и тд работает )
Во-вторых, бинарный файл отказывается переноситься в VS(открывается только в виде отдельного файла)

```
char name[] = "dgdrsek324dfg23ddf";

FILE* bin = fopen("bin.txt", "wb");
fwrite(name, sizeof(char), sizeof(name)/sizeof(char), bin);
fclose(bin);
```

Comment: А можно как-то попонятнее?... Что и как должно, по-вашему, кодироваться? Что значит "переноситься в VS"?

Comment: я имею в виду, что в текстовый бинарный файл наш массив чаров должен записываться не точь-в-точь, а кодироваться

Comment: А что такое "текстовый бинарный файл"? 8-/ А если должен кодироваться как-то — ну, напишите эту кодировку... С чего это он должен "кодироваться"?

Comment: Текст должен кодироваться как минимум по тому, что я заношу его в бинарный файл через спец функцию для этого

Comment: Наоборот же, в бинарном режиме ничего не кодируется, и байты пишутся «как есть». Вот только когда вы открываете свой бинарный файл _текстовым редактором_, он знает, что байт со значением `100` соответствует символу `d`, байт со значением `103` соответствует символу `g` и т.д. Ну и отображает эти байты соответствующим образом.

Comment: хорошо, а как мне открыть этот файл, чтобы я мог посмотреть этот текст в первоначальном/истинном виде?

Comment: Что такое «истинный вид»?

Comment: увидеть текст без перевода чисел в буквы или символы

Comment: Ну откройте в "Блокноте", например... Который "Notepad". Похоже, тут какие-то терминологические нестыковки...

Comment: Открыть файл [`hex-редактором`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)? Если вы хотите в своей программе отобразить байт не как символ (соответствующий значению байта в соответствии с используемой кодировкой), а как число, то используйте соответствующий способ вывода. Например: `char symbol = 'd'; printf("%d", (int)symbol);`.

Comment: по сути. моя программа должна создавать бинарный файл и записывать в него мою переменную в бинарном виде, но последний пункт отсутствует, не понимаю, почему